# How to use assetic to render an (unoptimised) image tag in Symfony2 + Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

Is there a shorter way to have Symfony2 + Assetic + Twig generate **image** urls than:

```
{% image '@ACMEBundle/Resources/public/img/longer.png' %}
  <img src="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endimage %}
```

Ideally, something like:

```
<img src="{{ bundle_resource_url('@ACMEBundle/Resources/public/img/shorter.png') }}" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your assets are in your web directory then use this instead:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/acme/img/shorter.jpg') }}" />
```

You can have Assetic install your assets for you by running this:

```
app/console assets:install path/to/web
```

Where `path/to/web` is your webroot.

Comment: That's what I have now, but I'd like to avoid having to run assets:install on my dev system if possible

Comment: Well, You can't really have it both ways. Personally, I have my environment setup so I don't have to run assets:install in my dev. All my paths are setup so the assets 'just work' as is. I put all my images and css in my web root instead of my main bundle. I only put my JS files in my bundle and use assetic to install them (so they get optimized in prod automatically).

Comment: Updated you answer with a solution that works for me. Cheers!

Comment: `app/console assets:install --symlink` will save you roundtrips, basically run it each time you add a bundle.